# parent able to make all childs draggable and when child is clicked they are draggable and sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to make draggable all the child elements if parent is clicked, i.e when  parent gets clicked  then try to drag all its child, also if I click on child then only its elements must be draggable.

I am using below code but it is working for child elements only, and when I try to drag all child elements from parent, can be done

```
$(function () {
   $(".droppable>div").sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable>div",
   }).disableSelection();        
});

<div name="list-a" class="droppable connectedSortable"> <h3>List A</h3>
   <div class="task - wrapper" id="child">
      <div class="draggable" id="1" name="1"> <a href="#">Element 1</a></div>
      <div class="draggable" id="2" name="3"> <a href="#">Element 2</a></div>
      <div class="draggable" id="3" name="3"> <a href="#">Element 3</a></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

1. List A
2. Element 1
3. Element 2
4. Element 3

Are able to drag and so are Element 1,2 & 3 but when I tried to drag whole list A along with its child then can't do so. please help.

**EDIT:**

[**JsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nicolai8/9zVDR/)

Comment: Can you provide a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: Please check above js fiddle link

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation https://jqueryui.com/sortable/ It specifically states that it makes the children of the div draggable, not the div itself. If you want to make #child draggable, you need to change

```
$(".droppable>div").sortable().disableSelection();
```

to

```
$(".droppable>div").sortable().disableSelection();
$(".droppable>div").draggable();
```

or

```
$(".droppable>div").sortable().disableSelection();
$(".droppable").sortable().disableSelection();
```

depending on what you're trying to do.
You've also added connectWith:".connectedSortable>div", but that makes no sense with the current markup, since it's the same div.

Comment: ok thanks @Daniel.So how can i improve the structure so that parent make all its child's drag-gable also its childs remain draggable and sortable

Comment: here is the link where i make a solution and its working              (http://jsfiddle.net/88amrit/bpGRL/)

Comment: Vanilla please only VANILLA !